# Безопасно очистить консоль

Tags: python, cmd

Мне нужно очистить консоль, казалось бы, ведь можно использовать

```
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Но на os жалуется dlint что это НЕ безопасный вариант. И советует использовать "subprocess"

Я пробую `subprocess.run('cls', shell=True)`

И теперь dlint жалуется что использовать `shell=True` не безопасно!

Я ставлю `shell=False` - Мой код не работает...

Как безопасно очистить консоль? Спасибо за любую полезную информацию!

Comment: Репозиторий dlint скоро уже три года как не обновляется. Зачем вам это старье?

Comment: `print("\033[H\033[J", end="")`

Comment: Что этот ваш dlint думает о `subprocess.call("clear")`?

Comment: dlint это устроит, но отсутствие shell= аналогично shell=False и таким образом, мой код не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Включить совместимость с vt100 и чистить эскейпом.

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    import ctypes
    kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
    kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)

print("\x1Bc" or "\x1b[2J", end='', flush=True)
```

Где `7 = ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`, а `-11 = open('r'\\.\CONOUT$'').fileno()`.

Интересно как оно поведет себя в gitbash и powershell - проверьте - отпишитесь в комментах.